# Remove an option from html multi select using prototype js library

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, html-select

I want to remove an option from a HTML multi select box using prototype. I tried the one below, and unfortunately it did not work

```
$('left').options.item($('left').selectedIndex)).remove();
```

I found some example with `.removedChild()`..I did not want to use them as it defeats the purpose of using JS library like Prototype.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the quotes. Try this

```
$('left').options.item($('left').selectedIndex).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably:

```
$('left').down(':selected').remove();
```

or `:checked` or `:active` or something. I assume.

**edit** Nope. Weird docs. http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/select/

**edit** `.select` > `.down`. http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/down/ Thanks @clockworkgeek

Comment: Replace `select` with [`down`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/down/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there was a bracket missing. The right line of code is,

```
$('left').options.item($('left').selectedIndex).remove();
```

Comment: please mark your answer as correct so people dont come here looking to help you